# QT coordinate transformation stratetgy

Tags: qt, coordinates

I would like to write a 2D QT application. The goal is to be able to draw rectangles and resize them and drag them around with the mouse. QT offers functionality to do that. The QGraphicsXxx classes natively operate with pixels, but I would like to be able to specify the items' dimensions and positions in length dimensions like meters.

I am looking for a good strategy for constructing an abstraction layer that allows object dimension representation in meters independent of pixels. I was thinking about extending QRectangle with with zoom information, for example, and methods to convert between real-world and screen, i.e. pixel, representation.

That should certainly be possible, but also smells like a road to coordinate-mapping hell. And like a lot of work for a problem that I wouldn't be surprised if it had already been solved more globally/elegantly and that I'm just not finding or understanding from the QT documentation.

Comment: did it work for you using the GraphicsView Framework?

Answer (score 2):

Use a QGraphicsScene to layout your objects, all sizes and positions are float and unit independent. Pixel come into play when displaying your Scene using a QGraphicsView. The zooming should be handled by the View so there is no need to do any coordinate transformation in your Scene. You just alter the transformation of your view to show whatever you want.

You can read more about it in the GraphicsView Framework documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html